# How to isolate a Solaris non-global zone in terms of resources

Tags: solaris, solaris-10

What are the best practices of setting up a non-global zone in Solaris 10 so that resources like CPU, memory, disk, etc. are capped? The intention is to isolate the zone so it doesn't use too much of any resource intended for other more important zones. It's on a ZFS file system.

Comment: Are you asking about how to do it or what values to set ?

Answer (score 1):

For cpu create resources pool and associate it to the zone.
For memory, use rcapd.
For disk, just set quotas on the zfs file system.

All this can be found in the resource management for oracle zones in the solaris admin guide [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/817-1592/rmpool-1.html)

hth